# Is there any date/time where this function could break?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I've not seen anything like this before. This is part of a function that returns the expected answer (a series of five dates)... sometimes. For example, it's been run at 6am, and the result is *sometimes* incorrect: one of the five dates, either at the first or last, can be missing. Other times, it's fine. Same code, run just a few hours later.

I know working with dates can be a lot more complicated than it first appears, but this has stumped me. I can only hope my inexperience with the DateTime objects is to blame.

```
    $start = new \DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day"))); 
    $end = new \DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-5 days"))); 
    $diff = $end->diff($start);
    $interval = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('-1 day');
    $period = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, $diff->days); 

    foreach($period as $date) {
        echo $date->format("Y-m-d"); // Sometimes first or last date will be missing
    }
```

So for example, if the code is run between `2020-07-05 00:00:00` and `2020-07-05 23:59:59`, it should return the last five dates:

```
2020-07-04
2020-07-03
2020-07-02
2020-07-01
2020-06-30
```

I've run the code with various date/times manually, and I cannot recreate the bug... and yet it happens once every few days in production.

This is just vanilla PHP, but it is being run as part of a Laravel project, should that factor into things. (The app timezone is set to "Europe/London".)

Comment: Interesting issue to say the least... I'd maybe try to add some logging, see if you can catch what dates this issue originates from. It could be based on the `count()` of `$period` (although `$period` isn't actually a `Countable`, so `count($period)` doesn't work), i.e. 5 vs 4, etc. Sidenote; since you're using Laravel, have you considered using `Carbon` (https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)? I find it a much more user-friendly Date library, and it's built into Laravel :)

Comment: Plus 1 for Carbon, but I will think about the vanilla PHP solution.

Comment: What timezone is your production server in relative to UTC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not keen on how you're defining `$start` and `$end`. If I'm not mistaken, if the server clock *happens* to tick to the next second between the two variables being defined, then your interval will be 3 days, 23 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds - instead of exactly 4 days. This messes up your definition of `$diff->days` to be `3` instead of `4`, leading to a missing date.

I would suggest a different approach here. Specifically, start with the current date, and subtract a day the number of times you want - since this appears to be hard-coded to 5.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$interval = new DateInterval("P1D");
for( $i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $date->sub($interval);
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
}
```

That `$i<5` can, of course, be refactored to `$i < DAYS` for some appropriate constant definition, to avoid the "magic number" and allow for changing in future development.

Comment: I think you're right. I've refactored my code so there's one central DateTime instead. Why leave that to chance? Seems like a bad idea now I look at it. (Also The actual code is actually part of a function that can take days as a parameter -- I'll simplified it with a hardcoded amount to share.) I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

With DateTime (and also strtotime) it is possible to process expressions like 'Today -3 Days'. Today is always 00:00 today. The calculation can be simplified as follows:

```
$days = 5;
for( $i=1; $i<=$days; $i++) {
  echo date_create("today -$i days")->format('Y-m-d')."<br>\n";
}
```